# Google Maps API - External link to map markers and open infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map populating with markers taken from an xml file that are stored in a database. Below the map I am pulling the same info from each marker and displaying them as listings. What I'm trying to to is create a `<a href="">` type link that will open the corresponding marker and infowindow beside each listing. Here is my page, it might better explain what I mean: http://poultry.ie/plugin/page/breeders

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

var redpin = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    new google.maps.Size(20,32),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(0,32)
);
var redpinshadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(37,32),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
);


   function load() {
       var gmarkers = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5076512854544, -7.701416015625),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
       downloadUrl("http://poultry.ie/plugins/CustomPages/pages/phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
          var breeds = markers[i].getAttribute("breeds");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b><br />" + address + "<br/>" + phone + "<br/>" + breeds;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        shadow: redpinshadow,
        icon: redpin,
        position: point
      });

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

    </script>
```

And the php that is dynamically displaying the listings (for this one county):

```
//Armagh
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE address='Armagh'")
 or die(mysql_error());
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print '<div class="county all armagh">'; 
 Print "<h4>".$info['name'] . "</h4> "; 
 Print "<em>".$info['address'] . "</em><br /> "; 
 Print "".$info['phone'] . "<br /> "; 
 Print '<a href="javascript:myclick(' . $info['id'] . ')">See on Map</a><br />';
 Print "<em>Breeds:</em> ".$info['breeds'] . "<hr/></div>";

 }
```

The `<a href="javascript:myclick(` is from a previous attempt at creating this, it doesn't actually have a function at the moment.

I have tried to apply many examples to my code without success as my knowledge of javascript is fairly limited to say the least. My above code might also not be the cleanest as it is my putting together from a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) (ported from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial) which loads markers from an xml file and has a clickable sidebar

Comment: Yeah I have tried copying that one before, but the sidebar_html is being automatically generated or something I couldn't figure out how to apply that part to my own code. I'll give it another go though, maybe someone could point me in the right direction on applying this one

Comment: You can remove the sidebar if you don't want it.  The markers are accessible with the same references that are automatically generated in the sidebar in the order they appear in the xml (so myclick(0) opens the infowindow on the first entry).

Comment: Okay I tried adding the code, javascript console shows that the myclick function is not being defined. I don't know much about javascript so any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for the help.